# bad error data when decrypting query string

Tags: asp.net

Please help this is so important for me.
I want encrypt and decrypt querystring with digital signature but I get this error:

Bad data error

Please help This is my encrypt code:

```
public partial class HashQueryString : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider senderCipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        senderCipher.FromXmlString(SENDER_KEYS);


        RSACryptoServiceProvider receiverCipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        senderCipher.FromXmlString(RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY);


        string plainText = "milad";
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] cipherTextBytes = receiverCipher.Encrypt(plainTextBytes, false);

        SHA1Managed hashalg = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashalg.ComputeHash(cipherTextBytes);
        RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter sigFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(senderCipher);
        sigFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
        byte[] signature = sigFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);

        string ciphertext = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        string signatureText = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
        hlDecrypt.NavigateUrl = "/DeHashQueryString.aspx?secret=" + Server.UrlEncode(ciphertext) + "&signature=" + Server.UrlEncode(signatureText) + "";
    }
    catch (CryptographicException x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace+"");
    }
}
}
```

And this is my decrypt code

```
public partial class DeHashQueryString : System.Web.UI.Page
{



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string secret = Request.QueryString["secret"];
    if (secret == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Secret QueryString was not provided...");
    }
    string signature = Request.QueryString["signature"];
    if (signature == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Signature was not found...");
    }
    byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
    byte[] signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    SHA1Managed hashalg = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] computedhash = hashalg.ComputeHash(cipherText);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider senderCipher = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    senderCipher.FromXmlString(SENDER_PUBLIC_KEYS);
    RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter sigDeFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(senderCipher);
    sigDeFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");

    if (!sigDeFormatter.VerifySignature(computedhash, signatureBytes))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Signature did not match from sender...");
    }
    decrypt(cipherText, RECEIVER_KEY);

}
private void decrypt(byte[] cipherText,string key)
{

    RSACryptoServiceProvider cipher =new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    cipher.FromXmlString(key);
    string str = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    byte[]plainTextBytes=cipher.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(str), false);
    Response.Write("My querystring was :" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes));
}
}
```

I write public/private key values completely

I delete public/private key value

This is receiver_public_key:
private const string RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY = "zUjNd9zRuTluiiwiLu47SiIgvGl8+YQPKuyklmwXzdH8WYP2VAWIR2rpRUIsNIv/2LMLlKM69KXCIkn9SQZ0XsetAQqUK0VKO9DLUtgkJ4loSq+V6BGhpdNzjKYObdXz00g12HukV/Wq4kslB9/ghgkCmQmC1mkxaCOPtQVcBfk=AQAB

6Q+Ro8TpTeT0eid9KImBsesRHGejTPxb6BCOhxMXd6RlD0BMrNk+wU62f09sVy3O55AML5fKX79d6kWDFIRDTQ==

4X1Z64BdfMFI7ffnneCIquObQ9A/mf40omjsnKuk+Sx2+VGQFc7VNaA9/hpeJ+cjAnUCM+LNDoNb8jAntq5fXQ==bcooyKZlZY164eSiYCtOzpq259OmqQik3xCVo+oJfxIRjXqz5CU/G99Rt22Z0wPAWXORWgY+jpZezpLKairYbQ==Wl15478VuCFdsMBgugx5uMJuPsb+NiCBx3R1HnRLMPB43YGqVJMHLu6A6Yx3n1Yp2Zo6v8BsnRxXhL93quZGoQ==kRyYgXh/aWJdk6w2AeootIwSuok6K2yfVR0kBXsEGMJzUafpZ9M6JFL+QpoeEbrxmkh3H4IhUcJiFF59Izxo7w==f+P0RdFnQwrZp/E41p4Kh/PdCyR4/IXeYTKOkzwCVHKW0TnaM5xCu6OKcmB4Y8A4g0uAUnii2RmPaYdI6b7ArdHwtBFfJA6Xrn6NZkLa/SP1DGCLxZI+B4+wY0oY1f6ZGwol4kPrvXysnclG9kUgb0YjVMZ9aqcwHZkkSuzTLhE=";

And this is sender_key:

"zUjNd9zRuTluiiwiLu47SiIgvGl8+YQPKuyklmwXzdH8WYP2VAWIR2rpRUIsNIv/2LMLlKM69KXCIkn9SQZ0XsetAQqUK0VKO9DLUtgkJ4loSq+V6BGhpdNzjKYObdXz00g12HukV/Wq4kslB9/ghgkCmQmC1mkxaCOPtQVcBfk=AQAB";

Comment: Please indent your code so that it will be formatted as such.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace+""); In asp.net do we have this...?I hope NO

Comment: "Bad Error"? What do u mean bad error(Please explain in detail).  And one more thing i would like to tell you "Every Error is Bad Error" there are none categorized as "GOOD Error" :)

Comment: @user3617997 which is used for SENDER_KEYS,RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY,hlDecrypt i copy ur code it shows me error here

Comment: byte[]plainTextBytes=cipher.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(str), false);When this code execute I get a error (bad data)

Comment: Hldecrypt is a hyperlink